# Rails update commits to database but save does not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a method as part of a model that changes some properties and commits them to the database. Originally, I had

#### Does not save to DB:

```
def accept
    status = Offer.ACCEPTED
    status_date = Time.now
    puts valid?  #true
    save!
end
```

This isnt actually working though. When I run it in the console, I just get

```
(0.1ms)  BEGIN
(0.1ms)  COMMIT
```

However, when I change to an `update` call, everything runs beautifully...

#### DOES save to DB:

```
def accept
    update({ status: Offer.ACCEPTED, status_date: Time.now })
end
```

I've been tweaking the validation recently so that may have something to do with it but I have been watching the `.valid?` values and it always is true. What am I misunderstanding here? Why isn't the data being saved?

Comment: try to replace `update` with `update!` and see if it raises any errors

Comment: No, no errors are given with `update!` but since `update` was successfully committing to the database, I wouldnt expect that `update!` would throw anything. `save!` is the method that isnt committing to the database and that isnt throwing errors either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're not using `self` in your writer methods. Ruby needs the explicit receiver on writer methods, otherwise it assumes that you're trying to assign a variable somewhere in your code. This approach will solve your issue:

```
def accept
  self.status      = Offer.ACCEPTED
  self.status_date = Time.now
  save!
end
```

I hope it helps !

Comment: Fantastic. This was the problem. Thanks a million.